# HTML SELECT JS onchange() disable comment box

Tags: javascript, html

This may be an absurdly easy question, but I'm new to JS.

I would like to have a SELECT box allowing a person to indicate where they heard about the event they're registering for.  There would be a comment box, disabled by default but if the user selects 'Other' in the SELECT option the comment box would become available.

I am aware of onchange() but I don't know how to trigger a response in the separate form element.  Any help?

Comment: You can add a [*change* listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event) to the select and if the value is "Other" (or whatever the value of that option is) set the disabled property of the related textarea to *false*, e.g. something like the following: `this.form.textAreaName.disabled = !(this.value == 'Other');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this.

HTML:

```
<select id="menu">
    <option value="0">News</option>
    <option value="1">Friends</option>
    <option value="2">Other</option>
</select>

<input id="comment" type="textbox" disabled="true"/>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('menu').addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.value == 2) {
        document.getElementById('comment').disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('comment').disabled = true;
    }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56fsyp0e/).

Comment: You could simplify this a little by incorporating RobG's comment and disabling it if the value isn't other.

`commentEl.disabled = !(this.value === 'other');`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/znma9ctd/

Comment: @Anton That's true, but since the OP is new to JS, I think being a little more verbose for intuition's sake could be helpful. Thank you though.

Comment: @flowstoneknight Thanks! I really appreciate the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this.

HTML:

```
<select id="IDE">
    <option value="0">Xcode</option>
    <option value="1">Android Studio</option>
    <option value="2">Others</option>
</select>

<input id="comment_box" type="textbox" disabled="true"/>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('IDE').addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.value == 2) {
        document.getElementById('comment_box').disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('comment_box').disabled = true;
    }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3nstrbk3/).